# Modifying the value of macro variable in SAS

Tags: sas

I created two macro variables in my sas code using the **%let** option.

```
data sasdata1.dataone;
set sasdata1.dataone ;
%let week=1;
%let sum=0;
do i=1 to 53;
%let sum= _W&week._NRX + &sum.;
week=&week+1;
end;
drop i;
week=&week;
sum=&sum.;
run;
```

the value of the week variable remains 1 even after the loop has executed. Which is the correct way to change the value of Macro variables?

Comment: I think you need to re-read doco on macro variable resolution, and how SAS tokenises and compiles code. There are a couple of issues, the main one being that you can't do this in open code, but you can do it *within the context of a macro* by using `%do &week=1 %to 53; <do something>; %end;`. Another issue (with the example code you've posted) is that you're using `i` as your iterator variable, but trying to increment a variable called `week`.

Comment: okay..so can i modify macro variables in the do something part of the do loop?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail of what you are doing in the loop.  Your current syntax is incorrect, however I'm guessing that you're over complicating the issue (i.e. you want the value of the macro variable week to be the same as the loop variable i).  We need to see how you're using these 2 values in the loop.

Comment: ok i will make an edit to my existing code.So basically i want sum to contain sum of 53 columns in my data set

Comment: Hmmm okay now you've edited your question I think my initial answer is superseded. Does your data contain 53 *columns* called `_W1_NRX` to `_w53_NRX`? And do you just want to create a variable called `sum` that adds them up for each `row` of data?

Comment: I wasn't able to modify the value of week using % let week.And i agree that my code is redundant in using value of week when i could have done only with i itself. But i am more interested in value of sum variable.Is there a way for me to sum value of given no of columns without using macro code?

Comment: yes @sasfrog it does contain 53 such columns .And yes i want to create a sum variable which contains the sum of these 53 values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your week variables are all next to each other in the dataset, you may want to consider a macro-less approach:

```
data sasdata1.dataone;
    set sasdata1.dataone;
    sum = sum(of _W1_NRX--_W53_NRX); *double dash means that the columns are next to each other with _W1_NRX as first and _W53_NRX as last;
run;
```

If your week variables end with the week number, they do not even need to be next to each other:

```
data sasdata1.dataone;
    set sasdata1.dataone;
    sum = sum(of _W1-_W53); *single dash implies that the suffix is numerically increasing;
run;
```

Clean and easy.

Comment: +1 @Shorack you arrived just at the right time, once the needless presence of macros in the solution had been scrutinised and ruled out :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Shorack.This is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 4):

Here's a quick example showing how to do this in the context of a macro. Run this and you can see in the log what's happening.

```
* 'week' is in scope within the macro only
  and iterates because of %do loop (no need
  to explicitly increment it ;
%macro test1;
  %do week=1 %to 10;
    %put &week;
  %end;
%mend;

%test1

* sum has global scope ;
%let sum=0;
* 'week' acts as per test1 above, but we
  explicitly manipulate 'sum' within each iteration ;
%macro test2;
  %do week=1 %to 10;
    %let sum=%eval(&sum+&week);
    %put in macro: week is &week, sum is now &sum;
  %end;
%mend;

%put before macro executes, sum is &sum;

%test2

%put after macro executes, sum is now &sum;
```